# What does a damage number of "<1" mean in Warhammer 40k?

Tags: warhammer-40k

I recently bought the Dark Imperium starter set for Warhammer 40k. This set includes two "mini-codices" for both Space Marines and Death Guard, covering only the units that are in the set.

What baffled me was the damage rating for the Bolters for the Space Marine Intercessors. They are written as "<1".

I could not find any information regarding this, neither in the core rulebook, nor in the Space Marine booklet. Furthermore, I could not find a relevant errata for the Space Marines or the Dark Imperium set.

What does "<1" as damage mean? Is this simply a typo and should be regarded as 1?

---

I finally managed to take a picture of the booklet:

[image: Photo of the german "Dark Imperium" booklet]

As can be seen, the "Boltgewehr" ("Bolt rifle") has a damage value of "<1".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are right, this is a typo. Elsewhere the D for such weapons is 1 (space marine codex etc). The other notations are typically a static number or a random value e.g. D6.

I think GW typically write out the full text: "a value greater than" rather than use > etc.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I find it strange that this typo has not been fixed, or at least been discovered and talked about by anyone.

Comment: No problem. I'll have to check my copy when I get a chance. I have to admit I didn't pay a great deal of attention to much of what came in the box other than the rulebook!

Comment: I just realized it yesterday when I explained the basic rules to my girlfriend. I was about to explain the damage, when I saw "<1" and was immediately confused.

Comment: I've checked my copies(!) and I can't find any examples of D<1 so I guess it's either been corrected or was introduced in a later print.

Comment: I added a picture to clarify